# Do I need a return at the end of iptables chain?

Tags: iptables

This is probably an incredibly basic question, but maybe there's some nuance and maybe it's been hashed out ad inifinitum and I'm oblivious to it.

I'm making a suite of custom iptables scripts that hang off the input and output chains.  I'm going to put `INPUT_MYTHING` and `OUTPUT_MYTHING` in the `INPUT` and `OUTPUT` chains.  Do I need to put a `RETURN` as the last rule in my chains?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No - the "return" is implied by the face that you "called" the `INPUT_MYTHING` chain from the `INPUT` chain.